# How do I make my menu appear on click with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I hover over the Menu it shows the dropdown menu.
I want it to happen on click.
I tried it but it didnt work for me.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="responsive-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu
      <ul>
        <li>Zomer</li>
        <li>Herfst</li>
        <li>Winter</li>
        <li>Lente</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;  
}

.responsive-menu {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:200%;
}

.responsive-menu ul li ul li {
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    border-top:solid 1px white;
}

.responsive-menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    font-size:60%;
    padding-top:30px;
}
.responsive-menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t78mf7jb/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HerrSerkers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822251/1763929) is a good answer, but there is another if you're willing to change your markup a little. You can simulate a `click` by using `checkbox` with it's `label`, like:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.responsive-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.responsive-menu ul li ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  border-top: solid 1px white;
}
.responsive-menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  font-size: 60%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#trigger {
  display: none;
}
#trigger:checked + .responsive-menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="trigger" />

<div class="responsive-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="trigger">Menu</label>
      <ul>
        <li>Zomer</li>
        <li>Herfst</li>
        <li>Winter</li>
        <li>Lente</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t78mf7jb/9/)

---

**Update** - as [HerrSerker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476951/herrserker) pointed out, there is a flaw regarding closing the menu - [check his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zn78sez7/) with a fix.

Comment: That's nice. But this won't work, if you have to support IE8, as `:checked` is a CSS3 selector and is not support in IE8. `:focus` is a CSS2.1 selector and is supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: @HerrSerker yea, that true if the OP needs IE8 support - `:checked` is a CSS3 selector which won't work for IE8. But doesn't IE8 have some issues with `tabindex` and `:focus`?

Comment: Maybe. Dunno. Didn't test it. It's just a sad situation that many of us still have to deal with the IE8 stuff. In 2016!

Comment: "**modern** web development issues"

Comment: There is one flaw with this approach. You can not close the menu by click outside actions, only by mouseout. And then the menu will show by mouseover after that, because the checkbox is still checked. I fiddled around a little bit and came up with a solution that works with on/off radio buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/zn78sez7/

Comment: That all depends what he OP really wants - maybe he wants to open/close the menu by **only** clicking the label. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer with your fix. :) Cheers

Answer (score 12):

Instead of the `:hover` pseudo-class you should use the `:focus` pseudo-class.

```
.responsive-menu ul li:focus ul {
    display:block;
}
```

To let the li gain focus it needs a `tabindex` attribute

```
<li tabindex="9999">Menu
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t78mf7jb/1/

---

#### amend

For not having the focus effect from browser add a `outline:none` style on the `li`

```
.responsive-menu ul li:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t78mf7jb/3/

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that a second click on the main menu element does not close the menu list. The click needs to be outside so that another element gains focus and the menu list disappears.